# AJAX call returns a undefined response php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Lets say that I have a php file and all that it contains is the below code

```
<?
  $response = array(
    'btn' => '',
    'keys' => 0
  );

  if(isset($_POST['method'])){
    $response['btn'] = "<button>This is a button</button>";
  }

  echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Now I make an ajax call to this php file like so

```
//Using wordpress ajax class
$.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', {action: 'key_bank', method: 'display'}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.btn);
});
```

Checking the log `response.btn` is undefined

What is happening here?

EDIT:

Here is the full script in case it helps to put things in to context a bit more. This is the file that the ajax call is being made to.

```php
<?
/**
 * @package   Key Bank
 * @author    Joseph WIlliamson
 */

 //Secure file from direct access
if (! defined('WPINC')) {
    die("This file is protected from being accessed directly");
}

$response = array(
    'btn' => '',
    'keys' => 0
);

$currentUrl = get_bloginfo('url');

if(isset($_POST['video_id'])){
    $videoId = $_POST['video_id'];
    //Get all rows in database
    //Check to see if the user is logged in
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        global $wpdb;

        //Current users ID
        $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $current_user_affiliate_id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_uap_affiliates WHERE uid=" . $current_user_id);
        $query = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_uap_referrals WHERE affiliate_id = ". $current_user_affiliate_id->id . " AND amount > 0");
        if(!empty($query)){
            $keys = (int) $query->amount;
            if($keys > 0){
                $newKeys = $keys - 1;
                $wpdb->update( 
                    'wp_uap_referrals', 
                    array('amount' => $newKeys), 
                    array( 'ID' => $query->id ), 
                    array( '%s' ), 
                    array( '%d' ) 
                );

                //Get current amount of votes on post
                $votes = get_post_meta($videoId,'contest-video-points',true);
                //Increase the votes by 1
                $votes += 1;
                //Update the post with the new value
                update_post_meta($videoId,'contest-video-points',$votes);

                $user_id = get_current_user_id();
                $user_id_to = get_post_meta((int)$_POST['video_id'],'contest-video-author',true);           
                setKeyData($user_id, $user_id_to );
            }
        }
    }
}

//Check to see if the user is logged in
if(is_user_logged_in()){
    global $wpdb;

    //Store variable for accessing keys in key bank
    $keys = 0;

    //Current users ID
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $current_user_affiliate_id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_uap_affiliates WHERE uid=" . $current_user_id);

    $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT SUM(amount) AS totalAmount FROM wp_uap_referrals WHERE affiliate_id = ".$current_user_affiliate_id->id."");
    $keys = (int)$query[0]->totalAmount;

    $response['keys'] = $keys;

    if(isset($_POST['method'])){
        switch($_POST['method']){
            case "display":
                $response['btn'] = '<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href = \''.$currentUrl.'/donate/\'">Earn more</button>';
                break;
            case "video_modal":
                if($response["keys"] > 0){
                    $response['btn'] = '<button class="btn btn-primary use-key-bank-btn">Give key from key bank</button>';
                }else{
                    $response['btn'] = '<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href = \''.$currentUrl.'/donate/\'">Earn more</button>';
                }
                break;
        }
    }else{
        $response['btn'] = 'Invalid method header sent';
    }

} else {
    $response['btn'] = "<button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='location.href=".$currentUrl."/wp-login.php?redirect_to=".$currentUrl."/open-doors-challenge/'>Please login to give key.</button>";
}


echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Your PHP script doesn't output any response. It just populates an array and doesn't do anything with it. At the end of it, do: `echo json_encode($response);`.

Comment: Add something like this : `echo json_encode($response["btn"]); die();` in the end of your function or script.

Comment: I also recommend that you use `<?php` instead of the short tag `<?`. Short tags are disabled as default since a few versions back.

Comment: Right I was minifying the code and forgot to add that part but it is already a part of the script I updated my question to reflect that @MagnusEriksson

Comment: `return` doesn't output anything. Use `echo` instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've corrected the code

Comment: You just changed from `return` to `echo` in your question. Does that mean that you have echo and that it doesn't work?

Comment: Dont you want `echo json_encode($response);` rather than `echo json_decode($response);` **TYPO**

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Good catch. I totally missed that one :-)

Comment: So I changed to echo `json_encode` but it is still undefined @MagnusEriksson

Comment: `response.data` doesn't exist.  `response` will be an object with the keys you defined in your array. It should be `response.btn`. I suggest doing some debugging like `console.log(response);` to see what you actually get. If the response is wrong, then check the network tab in your browsers dev tools and see what the actual request and response looks like.

Comment: Still is undefined in console.log @MagnusEriksson

Comment: What is undefined? Did you do the debugging I suggested? Is the above all the code or is there more that you haven't shown us? Do you get any errors in the console? Please understand that we can only help you if you give us a proper and _comprehensive_ explanation of your debugging.

Comment: I did a debug of `console.log(response)` and it is undefined so I went to the network tab and its almost impossible to sort through anything there https://outsource.technologyforthefuture.org/open-doors-challenge/?modalActive=true&video_id=508651

Comment: For testing purposes I made 3 logs for `response` `response.data` and `response.btn` all 3 returned undefined @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Do you think it would be more beneficial if I provided the full script that I am using? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I don't see any of the [wordpress ajax filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) in your PHP.  You need to put your code in a function and call that on the appropriate filter

Comment: So what does the network call show? What does `console.log(response)` show?

Comment: @mrben522 this is not neccesary if you are making a call to the file itself that is the point of `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')`

Comment: it shows undefined @epascarello